# Substract negative matrix element row wise from diagonal in R

Tags: r

I have an example matrix:

```
p <- matrix(c(0.5, 0.3, 0.3, -0.1, 0.6, 0.7, -0.2, -0.1), ncol = 4, byrow = T)

> p
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  0.5  0.3  0.3 -0.1
[2,]  0.6  0.7 -0.2 -0.1
```

with one or more negative elements in every row. The largest element is on the diagonal.
I want to create a function, which substracts row wise the negative values from the diagonal and then sets these elements to zero, so that the row sum is again 1.

I tried it myself with the apply function but had no luck until now.
Hope someone could help me.

Best Wishes
shearer

Comment: ``t(apply(p, 1, function (row) row-min(row)))``

Comment: Sorry, gives wrong results: `[1,]  0.6  0.4  0.4  0.0
[2,]  0.7  0.9  0.0  0.1`

Comment: Oops, I misread the question, sorry. Matthew's answer is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
negs <- p < 0
diag(p) <- diag(p) + rowSums(replace(p, ! negs, 0))
p[negs] <- 0
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]  0.4  0.3  0.3    0
# [2,]  0.6  0.4  0.0    0
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, works fine, thanks. But I can't figure out what `rowSums('[<-'(p, !negs, 0))` does. Can you please explain it?