# Add negative elements in matrix to whole row under the condition that all elements except diagonal are greater 0

Tags: r, matrix

According to my old question [Substract negative matrix element row wise from diagonal in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447827/substract-negative-matrix-element-row-wise-from-diagonal-in-r) , where I searched a way to add negative elements to the diagonal:

I now search a way to set all negative elements (except the diagonal) to 0 and substract their value from the whole row under the condition that all values (except the diag)are greater/equal 0.

The row Sums again should be 0.

```
p <- matrix(c(-0.3,0.2,0.2,-0.1, 0.1,-0.4,0.4,-0.1, 0.2,-0.1,-0.4,0.3, -0.1,0.2,0.1,-0.2), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)

> p
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] -0.3  0.2  0.2 -0.1
[2,]  0.1 -0.4  0.4 -0.1
[3,]  0.2 -0.1 -0.4  0.3
[4,] -0.1  0.2  0.1 -0.2
```

This should result in a matrix like this:

```
> p.result
       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]
[1,] -0.333  0.167  0.167  0.000
[2,]  0.067 -0.433  0.367  0.000
[3,]  0.167  0.000 -0.433  0.267
[4,]  0.000  0.167  0.067 -0.233
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#matrix of indicators, TRUE = off-diagonal negatives
ind <- row(p) != col(p) & p < 0

#vector of values to subtract from each row normalised to make sure row sums are still 1
subs <- rowSums(replace(p, !ind, 0))/rowSums(!ind)
p <- t(t(p) + subs)
p[ind] <- 0

p
            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]       [,4]
[1,] -0.33333333  0.1666667  0.16666667  0.0000000
[2,]  0.06666667 -0.4333333  0.36666667  0.0000000
[3,]  0.16666667  0.0000000 -0.43333333  0.2666667
[4,]  0.00000000  0.1666667  0.06666667 -0.2333333
```

you can round entries in the new matrix as necessary.

Comment: Maybe instead of `t(t(p) + subs)` just `p + subs[col(p)]` ?

Comment: @DavidArenburg your suggestion works for this particular example, where there is only one non-diagonal negative per row but it won't work if there are differing numbers of negatives in each row, so entries of `subs` are different. e.g. `subs <- c(1, 2, 3, 4); p <- matrix(0, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)`. then `p + subs[col(p)]` will be adding first entry of `subs` to first column of `p` etc. `p + subs[row(p)]` should do the job though and looks better than my line!

Comment: Yes I meant `subs[row(p)]`. It also more efficient than transposing the whole matrix twice.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works perfectly for the given small example. Sadly I came to the problem that I have a negative value beside the diagonal, which is higher than all other columns (except the diag) together. In this case the problem seems to be unsolvable and only the transfer to the diag may be the solution.