# Add negative elements in matrix to whole row under given conditions

Tags: r, matrix

According to my last question [Add negative elements in matrix to whole row under the condition that all elements except diagonal are greater 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047995/add-negative-elements-in-matrix-to-whole-row-under-the-condition-that-all-elemen)
, which resulted in a failure, when negative values were to large to distribute them to the row, I found the following algorithm, which I try to implement.

[image: Equation 1]

[image: Equation2]

I started to try to implement but could not find the solution until now.
This is the code until now:

```
p <- matrix(c(-0.3,0.2,0.2,-0.1, 0.1,-0.4,0.4,-0.1, 0.2,-0.1,-0.4,0.3, -0.1,0.2,0.1,-0.2), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)

ind1 <- row(p) != col(p)
ind2 <- row(p) != col(p) & p < 0
ind.diag <- row(p) == col(p)

maxMat <- apply(p, c(1,2), FUN = function(x){max(x, 0)})

Gi <- NA
Bi <- NA
Bi <- apply(p, 1, FUN = function(x){sum(max( -p[ind1], 0))})
for (i in 1:nrow(p)){
  Gi[i] <- abs(p[i, i]) + sum(maxMat[i, ])
}
GiBi <- cbind(Gi, Bi)


p.result <- p
p.result[ind2] <- 0
```

Comment: We're on a programming Q&A site, let's call an algorithm as being something which describe a logical flow (which may be the steps to solve an equation). Writing the algorithm to solve an equation is exactly your problem as it seems (I can't judge the equation, I don't understand it). If you wish help from more than mathematicians, describe it in plain English please :)

Comment: reading your other question, maybe an example with what you describe in  [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047995/add-negative-elements-in-matrix-to-whole-row-under-the-condition-that-all-elemen#comment52000903_32048722) could be better as your code is not usable as is for anyone (`maxMat` is undefined)

Comment: Sorry, added maxMat, which I forgot to show. Showing an example is not so easy since the value of the added value to every matrix entry depends on the value of the matrix entry, so I cannot show an example without having the code. I addition I think an example is not understandable in this case.

Comment: In this case I don't see how I may help you as I really can't understand the use case (a manually crafted 4x4 matrix as sample input and expected output with the edge cases your mentioned in the other topic comment sounds not that hard to create manually, but as I'm unsure on the edge case, I can't really guess it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was successfull in implementing the equations. The following, perhaps not very nice, code runs successfully.

```
#p <- matrix(c(-0.3,0.2,0.2,-0.1, 0.1,-0.4,0.4,-0.1, 0.2,-0.1,-0.4,0.3, -0.1,0.2,0.1,-0.2), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
p <- matrix(c(-0.1080,0.0907,0.0185,-0.0013, 0.0569,-0.1710,0.1091,0.0051, 0.0087,0.1092,-0.2293,0.1114, 0,0,0,0), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)

ind1 <- row(p) != col(p)
ind2 <- row(p) != col(p) & p < 0
ind.diag <- row(p) == col(p)
p.diag.zero <- p
diag(p.diag.zero) <- 0

maxMat <- apply(p.diag.zero, c(1,2), FUN = function(x){max(x, 0)})
maxMatNeg <- apply(p.diag.zero, c(1,2), FUN = function(x){max(-x, 0)})

Gi <- NA
Bi <- NA

for (i in 1:nrow(p)){
  Bi[i] <- sum( maxMatNeg[i, ])
}
for (i in 1:nrow(p)){
  Gi[i] <- abs(p[i, i]) + sum(maxMat[i, ])
}

p.result <- p

for( i in 1:nrow(p.result)){
  for( j in 1:ncol(p.result)){
    if( i!=j && p.result[i,j] < 0){
      p.result[i,j] <- 0}
    else if( Gi[i] > 0 ){
      p.result[i,j] <- round(p.result[i,j] - Bi[i] * abs(p.result[i,j])/ Gi[i], 4)}
    else if( Gi[i] == 0 ){
      p.result[i,j] <- p.result[i,j]}
  }
}
```